# Undefined while Fetching news api from newsapi.org

Tags: javascript, json, api, alan, newsapi

I am trying to make a voice controlled news app using Newsapi.org API key the code is working fine but it's not fetching any news and just running the undefined condition.

```
intent('What does this app do?', 'What can I do here?', 'What do you do?',
      reply('This is a news project.'));


const API_KEY = '0e46583fc8374xxxxxxx29373ad54';
let savedArticles = [];

// News by Source
intent('Give me the news from $(source* (.*))', (p) => {
    let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
    
    if(p.source.value) {
        NEWS_API_URL = `${NEWS_API_URL}&sources=${p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join('-')}`
    }
    
    api.request(NEWS_API_URL, (error, response, body) => {
        const { articles } = JSON.parse(body);
        
        if(typeof articles === 'undefined') {
            p.play('Sorry, please try searching for news from a different source');
            return;
        }
        
        savedArticles = articles;
        
        p.play({ command: 'newHeadlines', articles });
        p.play(`Here are the (latest|recent) ${p.source.value} news.`);
  
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi James, I've added the undefined condition for the same. Also, [here](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines) it's clearly visible that `articles`  property exists.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you are destructuring the response to get the articles property.  What does the entire response contain?  Check network tab in dev tools to make sure you're not getting an error message.